# How to get data from many to many table, without custom query?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

Well I create ManyToMany relation, which works fine, but when I tried to get data it returns me empty object:

How i tried to get data (Controller):

```
    $userRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $user = $userRepo->find($user->getId());
    $test = $user->getFavouriteArticles();
    dump($test); exit;
```

User Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var favouriteArticles[]
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Article")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_favourite_articles",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     */
    private $favouriteArticles;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->favouriteArticles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return favouriteArticles[]
     */
    public function getFavouriteArticles(): object
    {
        return $this->favouriteArticles;
    }

    /**
     * @param favouriteArticles[] $favouriteArticles
     */
    public function setFavouriteArticles(array $favouriteArticles): void
    {
        $this->favouriteArticles = $favouriteArticles;
    }

    /**
     * Add user
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Article $article
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addFavouriteArticle(Article $article)
    {
        $this->favouriteArticles[] = $article;

        return $this;
    }
```

How I add User favourite articles:

```
public function addToFavourites($category, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $article = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Article")->find($id);
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $user = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:User")->find($user->getId());
    $user->addFavouriteArticle($article);
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
```

DB (user_favourite_articles table):

```
|user_id| article_id |
|____________________|
|    3  |      8     |
|    3  |      9     |
```

Current `user_id` is 3

Result from dump is and i cannot show `favouriteArticles`:

```
PersistentCollection {#7796 ▼
  -snapshot: []
  -owner: User {#7563 ▼
    #id: 3
    -firstName: "test"
    -favouriteArticles: PersistentCollection {#7796}
    #username: "test@test.com"
    #usernameCanonical: "test@test.com"
    #email: "test@test.com"
    #emailCanonical: "test@test.com"
    #enabled: true
    #salt: null
    #password: "$2y$13$.8Ky5Jj71PUsGD9E04nre./xClPVZ/Uiia40PTQjGmMAqOFpW2mwi"
    #plainPassword: null
    #lastLogin: DateTime {#7559 ▶}
    #confirmationToken: null
    #passwordRequestedAt: null
    #groups: null
    #roles: []
  }
```

Comment: Could you post the complete code for the User-entity? Do you follow the Doctrine-guidelines of using an ArrayCollection, i.e. do you set the ArrayCollection in your User's constructor? Also, I don't see a `cascade`-option on your `$favouriteArticles`-property. Are you sure Doctrine writes these changes when doing `$em->persist($user)`?

Comment: @dbrumann It's updated

Comment: Thanks. The constructor, getFavouriteArticle and addFavouriteArticle look fine. setFavouriteArticles is problematic (your replace the ArrayCollection with an array), but let's worry about that when we fixed the problem at hand. There is still the issue with the missing cascade. Could you try `@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Article", cascade={"all"})` (adding the cascade)?

Comment: `* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Article", cascade={"all"})` It's done. Same result.

Comment: Does updating the user (adding a favourite article) and then finding the articles work, now?

Comment: User's favourite articles adding works fine when I call this method `public function addToFavourites($category, $id)` but still shows me `-favouriteArticles: PersistentCollection {#7796}`

Comment: PersistentCollection is fine, but how many items does it contain? The PersistentCollection is a special type of Collection that Doctrine uses internally. Usually you don't have to worry about the class type. You could also try `dump( $test->toArray())` instead to get the actual array of favourited articles.

Comment: `$test->toArray()` works perfect it returns my exactly 2 articles with Id's 8 and 9.

Comment: Could it be that the result was just misleading? You get a list of favourite articles. Since the articles links back to the user (owner-property), this owner contains the same collection #7796 that you already have as its favouriteArticles property.

Comment: How can I check ?

Comment: Well, if it works even without the `cascade` then it probably was that. In the future you might want to move the `->toArray()` inside the getter and make sure that you always return an array instead of the collection object.